# Are all Inquisitors former Jedi? If they are, why does the Empire trust them?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi

We see in the new episode of *Obi-Wan Kenobi* that Reva (better known as The Third Sister) was a former Jedi youngling who

> joined the empire to take revenge from Darth Vader.

This got me wondering if all Inquisitors were former Jedi, and if they are, then why does the Empire trust them?

I mean, even after Vader saw Reva betraying him, didn't he have trust issues with the Inquisitors?

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Inquisitorius - Some were and some were force-sensitive children that had been kidnapped

Comment: "why does the Empire trust them?" I'm not sure the Empire trusted them. In the end it seemed Vader was suspicious of Reva in the first place!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Are all Inquisitors former Jedi?

No. As Valorum noted in his comment, *some* were - the *Star Wars: Rebels* episode "Shroud of Darkness", for example, reveals that the Grand Inquisitor used to be one. Others were Force-sensitive children that had been kidnapped and raised to be part of the Inquisitorius. While Reva *was* a Jedi youngling at one time, the frequent mentions of her having been "found in a gutter" by the Inquisitorius suggest that this was how she joined the order.

> If they are, then why does the Empire trust them?

There are two layers to this.

Firstly, backstabbing is endemic to the Sith. They backstabbed each other so much that they basically wiped themselves out, at which point Darth Bane instigated the Rule of Two: one Sith to hold power, one Sith to crave it. Eventually, the apprentice grows strong enough to kill the master and take on an apprentice of their own, and the cycle continues.

We can see that the Inquisitors have a similar mindset: Reva tries to kill the Grand Inquisitor and take his position, and in *Rebels*, the Fifth Brother and Seventh Sister make a *very* poor team, constantly undermining one another and trying to take the glory for themselves.

The difference between the Inquisitors and the Sith - and this is my second point - is that the Inquisitors are deliberately *not* trained to the point of reaching or surpassing their masters (i.e. the Emperor and Vader). They are more than a match for an untrained Padawan, but every time we see an Inquisitor up against a truly skilled opponent - Ahsoka and Maul in *Rebels*, Darth Vader in *Kenobi* - they are utterly outmatched.

So my answer to "Why does the Empire trust the Inquisitors" is "they don't, but they planned for that eventuality and they're more than capable of dealing with any Inquisitors who turn on them", as demonstrated by Vader handing Reva's ass to her.